# Decode code of Magento 2 Extension

Tags: php, magento-2.2.5, third-party-module

I'm working on customization of extension functionality. I have to add my custom code with it, but when I have checked code all the codes are encoded and I can't see actual code there.

So can anyone please help me how to decode and get code in original form?

Code of Block file is as below.

```
$qfQUcKlNMJarFuvYADxSwGtijZhHTXoPBLOVmRnebzWgsyEIpkC1507437326 = file(__FILE__);eval(base64_decode("aWYoIWZ1bmN0aW9uX2V4aXN0cygid1VQRVZHeEZBSldxb2NTcnNIT1lNTHBLQmZYTmdtUWtoSWV0aXVqVHlhdm5sYnpSRFpDMTUwNzQzNzMyNiIpKXtmdW5jdGlvbiB3VVBFVkd4RkFKV3FvY1Nyc0hPWU1McEtCZlhOZ21Ra2hJZXRpdWpUeWF2bmxielJEWkMxNTA3NDM3MzI2KCRnLCRiPTApeyRhPWltcGxvZGUoIlxuIiwkZyk7JGQ9YXJyYXkoMTEzNSwzNDQsNDApO2lmKCRiPT0wKSAkZj1zdWJzdHIoJGEsJGRbMF0sJGRbMV0pO2Vsc2VpZigkYj09MSkgJGY9c3Vic3RyKCRhLCRkWzBdKyRkWzFdLCRkWzJdKTtlbHNlICRmPXRyaW0oc3Vic3RyKCRhLCRkWzBdKyRkWzFdKyRkWzJdKSk7cmV0dXJuKCRmKTt9fQ=="));eval(base64_decode(wUPEVGxFAJWqocSrsHOYMLpKBfXNgmQkhIetiujTyavnlbzRDZC1507437326($qfQUcKlNMJarFuvYADxSwGtijZhHTXoPBLOVmRnebzWgsyEIpkC1507437326)));eval(bfTFLZBezUnhpwNugKliQMWAxHERqJOjVDvcIGCStPYsmaryXok1507437326(wUPEVGxFAJWqocSrsHOYMLpKBfXNgmQkhIetiujTyavnlbzRDZC1507437326($qfQUcKlNMJarFuvYADxSwGtijZhHTXoPBLOVmRnebzWgsyEIpkC1507437326,2),wUPEVGxFAJWqocSrsHOYMLpKBfXNgmQkhIetiujTyavnlbzRDZC1507437326($qfQUcKlNMJarFuvYADxSwGtijZhHTXoPBLOVmRnebzWgsyEIpkC1507437326,1)));__halt_compiler();aWYoIWZ1bmN0aW9uX2V4aXN0cygiYmZURkxaQmV6VW5ocHdOdWdLbGlRTVdBeEhFUnFKT2pWRHZjSUdDU3RQWXNtYXJ5WG9rMTUwNzQzNzMyNiIpKXtmdW5jdGlvbiBiZlRGTFpCZXpVbmhwd051Z0tsaVFNV0F4SEVScUpPalZEdmNJR0NTdFBZc21hcnlYb2sxNTA3NDM3MzI2KCRhLCRoKXtpZigkaD09c2hhMSgkYSkpe3JldHVybihnemluZmxhdGUoYmFzZTY0X2RlY29kZSgkYSkpKTt9ZWxzZXtlY2hvKCJFcnJvcjogRmlsZSBNb2RpZmllZCIpO319fQ==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
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that all code of this extension is encoded. So it's very difficult to decode by self. So you have to do any customization then you should ask Extension provider how to decode and change this code.

Answer (score 0):

Do **not** ask your extension provider ... just stop using his extensions ;)

The encode code looks like ...

```
<?php function wUPEVGxFAJWqocSrsHOYMLpKBfXNgmQkhIetiujTyavnlbzRDZC1507437326($g, $b = 0) {
    $a = implode("
", $g);
    $d = array(1135, 344, 40);
    if ($b == 0) $f = substr($a, $d[0], $d[1]);
    elseif ($b == 1) $f = substr($a, $d[0] + $d[1], $d[2]);
    else $f = trim(substr($a, $d[0] + $d[1] + $d[2]));
    return ($f);
}
if (!function_exists("wUPEVGxFAJWqocSrsHOYMLpKBfXNgmQkhIetiujTyavnlbzRDZC1507437326")) {
    function wUPEVGxFAJWqocSrsHOYMLpKBfXNgmQkhIetiujTyavnlbzRDZC1507437326($g, $b = 0) {
        $a = implode("
", $g);
        $d = array(1135, 344, 40);
        if ($b == 0) $f = substr($a, $d[0], $d[1]);
        elseif ($b == 1) $f = substr($a, $d[0] + $d[1], $d[2]);
        else $f = trim(substr($a, $d[0] + $d[1] + $d[2]));
        return ($f);
    }
}
```

From: https://www.unphp.net/